# Would you please explain why I am getting error in this testcase 99?

Tags: c

https://codeforces.com/contest/61/problem/A
Here in the testcase 99 of this I am experiencing an error which I am not getting in codeblocks. What I have identified is, after printing the needed output correctly, some `1`s are being printed. I am not getting the fact why these `1`s are being printed.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char x[100],y[100];
    scanf("%s%s",&x,&y);
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(x);i++)
    {
        if(x[i]==y[i])
        {
            printf("0");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("1");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Image: Error in testcase 99](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zsgal.jpg)

Comment: If the strings have a length 100, the size of the arrays should be 101. You may also add an EOL at the end. And please remove the [python] tag.

Comment: You have not included the testcase.

Comment: That use of `scanf` is dangerous. It can lead to a buffer-overflow, that will produce undefined behaviour.  Use a good static analysis tool, or better use a safer language such as `golang`.

Comment: I have linked the image of testcase 99...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Please don't use screenshots of texts, copy the text verbatim. It would have helped a lot if you had posted the input and the output as text. -- Anyway, I counted the number of characters of the input. Your character arrays are too small.

Answer (score 1):

That use of `scanf` is dangerous. It can lead to a buffer-overflow, that will produce undefined behaviour (behaviour may be different on different platforms, or even each time that you run the program).

Turn on compiler warnings. Use a good static analysis tool, or better use a safer language such as `golang`. Then use `scanf` format strings that prevent buffer overrun. On `gcc` the option `-Wall` will turn on this warning. You may also want to turn on some other warnings, or turn up the  level to be more strict (especially for new code).

Comment: It would be useful to include how the use of `scanf` could be improved.

Comment: @Gerhardh true but there is much said about buffer overflow elsewhere.

Comment: @Gerhardh instead I added a note about enabling `GCC` warnings.

Comment: You also did not link to some "elsewhere" that addresses buffer overflow in `scanf`. Without even giving a tiny hint about adding some flags to the format specifier, a beginner will hardly find it.

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues in your code:

```c
    char x[100],y[100];
    scanf("%s%s",&x,&y);
```

The type of second and third argument for `scanf` is not correct. They may have correct value, but strictly speaking they are wrong.
You need a `char*` but you provide a `char (*)[]`. You should just use `x,y` without the `&`.

Also you do not take care about potential buffer overflows.

To avoid buffer overflows, you should add a length limit to your format specifier. It must be one less than the size of your arrays.

Also you are required to deal with numbers up to 100 digits. That does not fit into your buffers.
If you need to handle strings of length 100, your arrays must have size 101.

You don't do this. If you get a string that is too long for one of your arrays, you will probably overflow into the next buffer losing the terminator byte.

That said, the 2 lines above should look like this:

```c
    char x[101],y[101];
    scanf("%100s%100s", x, y);
```

Additionally you should *always* check return value of `scanf` and other IO functions.

To improve performance a bit, you should also not call `strlen` in each iteration of the loop. Instead you should call it once before the loop and store the value to use it in the loop condition.